# Global variable appears to lose value (swift)

Tags: swift

This is my code to extract data from firebase.
listofnames(double dimensional) and  names(single dimensional) are global arrays of type String.

However, when I print `listofnames` an empty array is displayed in the output window whereas, if I comment the first line (self.listofnames = [[]]) the code functions properly.

I have linked ref with Firebase database

Please help.

```
var databasehandle:FIRDatabaseHandle?

let time = ["8AM - 9AM", "9AM - 10AM","10AM - 11AM", "11AM -12PM", "12PM - 1PM","1PM - 1:30PM","2PM - 3PM","3PM - 4PM","4PM - 5PM","5PM - 6PM","6PM - 7PM","7PM - 7:30PM"]

var ref:FIRDatabaseReference!
var day: String = "Monday"
var users :String = "First years"

func loaddata()
{
    self.listofnames = [[]]
    for x in 0...((time.count)-1)
    {
        ref.child(users).child(day).child(time[x]).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: {(snapshot) -> Void in
            if let namesfromFirebase = snapshot.value as? [String:Any]
            {
                let y = namesfromFirebase.count
                for i in 1...y
                {
                    self.names.append(namesfromFirebase["s"+"\(i)"] as! String)
                }
            }
            self.listofnames.append(self.names)
            self.names = []
        })
    }
    print(self.listofnames)
    self.tableView.reloadData()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`observeSingleEvent` works asynchronously, the closure is called later.

There is an easy solution: Move the two lines **into** the closure:

```
func loaddata()
{
    self.listofnames = [[]]
    for x in 0..<time.count // no parentheses and math needed when using `..<`
    {
        ref.child(users).child(day).child(time[x]).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: {(snapshot) -> Void in
                if let namesfromFirebase = snapshot.value as? [String:Any]
                {
                    let y = namesfromFirebase.count
                    for i in 1...y
                    {
                        self.names.append(namesfromFirebase["s"+"\(i)"] as! String)
                    }
                }
                self.listofnames.append(self.names)
                self.names = []
                print(self.listofnames)
                self.tableView.reloadData()
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: I will be using the contents of the variable from a different function... and the array then remains empty

Comment: Then you need a completion handler or put the code which uses the variable in the closure, too.